# Using Pillow's Image.save() function throws an AttributeError when trying to download an image from a page using Splinter

Tags: python, web-scraping, attributeerror, python-imaging-library, splinter

I am trying to download an image from a webpage using a combination of the Splinter browser library (with ChromeDriver) and the Pillow library. I am using an instance of a Chrome browser to login to the website and navigate to the page with the image on it, and then using the `browser.find_by_tag()` method to locate the image.

I then try to use the `Image.save()` method of Pillow, but it throws this error:

```
C:\Users\my.name\Documents\Development\Python-Scripts>my_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my.name\Documents\Development\Python-Scripts\my_script.p
y", line 31, in <module>
    my_function()
  File "C:\Users\my.name\Documents\Development\Python-Scripts\my_script.p
y", line 19, in my_function
    farmer_image = Image.save(farmer_image_brobj)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'save'
```

And my code:

```
from splinter import Browser
from PIL import Image

def my_function():
    with Browser('chrome') as browser: 
        url = "http://www.blah/login.aspx"
        url_two = "http://www.blah/ImagePageParent.aspx"

        browser.visit(url)
        browser.fill('un', 'blah')
        browser.fill('pw', 'blah')
        browser.find_by_name('btn').click()
        browser.visit(url_two)
        browser.find_link_by_partial_href('partial_href').click() 

        farmer_image_brobj = browser.find_by_tag('img')
        farmer_image = Image.save(farmer_image_brobj)

        browser.visit(url_two)
        browser.quit()

my_function()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [effbot example](http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm), you are calling it the wrong way. Instead of

```
    farmer_image_brobj = browser.find_by_tag('img')
    farmer_image = Image.save(farmer_image_brobj)
```

You should use the `save()` method on the instance of Image. So first, open the image:

```
farmer_imag = Image.open(...) #something doing with farmer_image_brobj
```

for instance, using requests, you could do something like:

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com/image.jpg')
farmer_image = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
```

then save it by giving the path:

```
farmer_image.save('my_image.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, forgive me being a noob at this, but when you say "# something doing with farmer_image_brobj" what should I be doing with it?

Comment: @DrBrown From `farmer_image_brobj`, you should retrieve the path (usually in the src attribute).. Then, you have to _get_ the content of the image (like the example using requests).

Comment: It worked thank you! Had to change the imports to import io and the StringIO to io.BytesIO.